# Collision: How can I calculate the effect of an object below 1 kg on another heavier object after colliding

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, kinetic-theory

I have a question on collision:

1. A light object (0.75 kg) is travel in velocity V m/s.

2. This object collide into another object which is about 9.5 times of its weight.

3. So, the question is how can I determine what happen next? (I mean the heavier object will move? / How fast the minimum speed of the light object should travel to push the heavier object?)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you considering elastic or inelastic collision?